# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{x^4+16}\,dx$

Tags: improper-integrals, mathematical-physics, residue-calculus

It's a very simple problem. I put it into wolfram alpha and it gave me a hugely complicated answer. This makes me think that I am supposed to be doing it differently.

I believe I am supposed to use the residue theorem for this answer but have no idea how. $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^4+16}dx = 2\pi i \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} Res\big(\frac{x^2}{x^4+16}\big)$$ I have no idea what Res() is or how to use this in any way.

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

Sorry, I typed the equation in wrong, I just corrected it from $\frac{x^4}{x^2+16}$ to $\frac{x^2}{x^4+16}$

Comment: Why not $x=4\tan t$

Comment: Are you sure that's not supposed to be $x^2/(x^4 + 16)$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog is correct, I have since updated the equation, thank you

Comment: Have you not taken a course in complex analysis? That's were residues are introduced, explained and utilized in evaluating integrals like this. Presumably that course is a prerequisite here? Do observe that you only need finitely many residues here. That infinite sum looks strange.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I have not. This is for an introduction to mathematical physics course and is the first time I have seen the residue theorem. The only prerequisites are calculus, linear algebra, and quantum/relativistic physics.

Comment: In that case I would point fingers at whoever designed this course. Unfortunately, you are no well placed to point fingers at the teacher. Anway, [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) **is** a powerful tool. Though physicists often resorted to books with extensive tables of integrals. Nowadays Wolfram Alpha has replaced those books for many. Neither are available at exam conditions, so...

Answer (score 5):

If you call the integral $I$, then
$$2I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{z^2\,dz}{z^4+16}.$$
This can be done by the "semicircle" method in contour integration, and
equals $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues of the integrand of the
poles in the upper half plane. These poles are at $2\zeta$ and $2\zeta^3$
where
$\zeta=\exp(\pi i/4)$. The residue at $2\zeta$ is
$$\lim_{z\to2\zeta}\frac{(z-2\zeta)z^2}{z^4+16}=\frac{(2\zeta)^2}
{4(2\zeta)^3}=\frac{1}{8\zeta}.$$
Now do the very  similar calculation for the other residue and put the
pieces together.

Comment: I am having trouble following the step in removing the limit, does the $(z-2\zeta)$ factor out from $(z^{4} + 16)$?

Comment: It does indeed, but it's easier to consider the derivative of $z^4+16$ at $z=2\zeta$. @Big_Tubbz

Comment: Thank you for everything so far, I have found a way to solve the equation, but I keep getting the wrong answer. is the residue at $2 \zeta = \frac{1}{8 \zeta^{3}}$?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the residue at $2 \zeta^{3}$

Comment: @LordTheShark I am the downvote, and it was accidental. If you edit your answer I can fix it, but for now it’s been too long since my vote so I cannot change it.

Comment: @JavaMan I made a minor edit...

Comment: @lordshark Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With substitution $x^2=4\tan u$ then
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^2}{x^4+16}\ dx
&= \dfrac14\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\tan u} \ du \\
&= \dfrac14\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2(\frac34)-1}u \cos^{2(\frac14)-1}u\ du \\
&= \dfrac18\beta(\dfrac34,\dfrac14) \\
&= \dfrac18\Gamma(\dfrac34)\Gamma(\dfrac14) \\
&= \color{blue}{\dfrac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}}
\end{align}
here $\beta(x,y)$ is [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and 
$$\Gamma(1+x)\Gamma(1-x)=\dfrac{\pi x}{\sin\pi x}$$

Comment: What is $β$ and what are the $Γ$?

Comment: The beta and gamma functions. But the more frequent notation for the beta function is $B(x,y)$ rather than $\beta(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide another complex method.
Let $f(z)=\frac{z^2\ln (-z)}{z^4+16}$. Taking $C$ as the keyhole contour (small circle around the origin, upward of positive real axis, big circle, downward of positive real axis).
$$\int_C f(z)dz=2\pi i\sum_{z:\text{roots of $z^4+16$}}\operatorname{Res}(f(z))=2\pi i(-\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt2}),$$
$$I=\frac{2\pi i}{-2\pi i}(-\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt2})=\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt2}$$